# XSLT - Transform XML then remove empty parents and childern

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a current stylesheet which when applied to an XML file it comes back with parents and children with empty fields.

My current XSLT looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="pdml/packet">
        <PacketSRC id="{proto/field[@name='ip.src']/@show}">
            <PacketDST>
                <xsl:value-of select="proto/field[@name='ip.dst']/@show"/>
            </PacketDST>
            <PacketFLAG>
                <xsl:value-of select="proto/field[@name='tcp.flags']/@showname"/>
            </PacketFLAG>
            <PacketPORT> 
                <xsl:value-of select="proto/field[@name='tcp.dstport']/@show"/>
            </PacketPORT>
        </PacketSRC>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the transform is complete, some whole PacketSRCs are completely empty whilst others have empty PacketPORTs and PacketFLAGs.

The correct output looks like this:

```
<PacketSRC id="192.168.1.211">
  <PacketDST>192.168.1.254</PacketDST>
  <PacketFLAG>.... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)</PacketFLAG>
  <PacketPORT>3306</PacketPORT>
</PacketSRC>
```

But because of the data being accessed some may show up as (both of which need removing):

```
<PacketSRC id="">
  <PacketDST></PacketDST>
  <PacketFLAG></PacketFLAG>
  <PacketPORT></PacketPORT>
</PacketSRC>
```

OR

```
<PacketSRC id="192.168.1.211">
  <PacketDST>192.168.1.254</PacketDST>
  <PacketFLAG></PacketFLAG>
  <PacketPORT></PacketPORT>
</PacketSRC>
```

I have looked to other stack overflow answers for help but I cannot relate them to my scenario. So my question is if any of the values or fields are empty remove it from the final transformation.

Comment: The problem is, the input differs greatly and the reason for the XSLT in the first place was to narrow down to only specific data from certain input. The three above pieces of XML are outputs from the XSLT.

Comment: It would help greatly if you showed the INPUT XML. All you've shown is the XSLT and the OUTPUT XML.

Comment: The INPUT XML style is PDML. If I were to show 'Packet' it could change drastically to the next one. If you get what I mean.

Comment: I agree with @JimGarrison.  You should be able to cull a representative sample of PDML that exhibits your problem.  I've answered your question the best I could below, but had you included actual input XML and expected output XML, we could have provided you with working, tested code instead of just a sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way of making it so that if one of them (packetDST,
>   packetFLAG, packetPORT) is empty then move to next pdml/packet?

Sure, simply create a test surrounding `PacketSRC`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="pdml/packet">
        <xsl:if test="proto[    field[@name='ip.dst']/@show
                            and field[@name='tcp.flags']/@showname
                            and field[@name='tcp.dstport']/@show
                            ]">
          <PacketSRC id="{proto/field[@name='ip.src']/@show">
            <PacketDST>
              <xsl:value-of select="proto/field[@name='ip.dst']/@show"/>
            </PacketDST>
            <PacketFLAG>
              <xsl:value-of select="proto/field[@name='tcp.flags']/@showname"/>
            </PacketFLAG>
            <PacketPORT> 
              <xsl:value-of select="proto/field[@name='tcp.dstport']/@show"/>
            </PacketPORT>
          </PacketSRC>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And if you want `PacketSRC` to be omitted when you have no data for its `@id`, you can check for that too:

```
    <xsl:if test="proto[    field[@name='ip.src']/@show
                        and field[@name='ip.dst']/@show
                        and field[@name='tcp.flags']/@showname
                        and field[@name='tcp.dstport']/@show
                        ]">
```

Comment: Is there a way of making it so that if one of them (packetDST, packetFLAG, packetPORT) is empty then move to next pdml/packet?

Comment: Because it now has some that look like:   `<PacketSRC id="192.168.1.211">
    <PacketDST>192.168.1.254</PacketDST>
  </PacketSRC>`

Which need to be deleted.